# vue component doesn't show data

Tags: laravel, vue.js, components

Axios loads data without any problem,   doesn't show any data, Laravel Mix builds without error.

I have following code:

index.html (body)

```
<div id="app">
    <posts></posts>
</div>
```

In app.js I use this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

// global declare axios
window.axios = require('axios');

import Posts from './components/Posts';
Vue.component('posts', Posts);

new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    props: {
        posts:[{
            userId: [Number],
            id: [Number],
            title: [String, Number]
        }]
    }
});
```

In the Posts.vue component I create a template and a script loading the data when mounted:

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="post in posts" v-text="post.title"></li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
    export default {


        data: function() {
            return {
                posts: null,
            }
        },

        // when stuff is loaded (document ready)
        mounted: function() {

            // use placeholder data for tests, capture asynchronous data from site using this.
            axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
                .then(response => this.posts = response.posts)
                .catch(error => this.posts = [{title: 'No posts found.'}])
                .finally(console.log('Posts loading complete'));
        },
    }
</script>
```

So the data should be shown as a ul list:

```
<ul>
  <li>
     title
  </li>
  <li>
     title
  </li>
  <li>
     title
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below, I've made comments on the bits that need changing.

```
data() {
    return {
        posts: [] // this should be an array not null
    };
},

// you can do this on created instead of mounted
created() {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then(response => {
            this.posts = response.data; // add data to the response
        });
```

Comment: This did the trick, thanks for that!  created or mounted works - which would be the best practise? tutorials tend to use the mounted function.

Comment: Created should be fine for this, if you're working with something which relies on an element being ready in the DOM, use mounted. Please don't forget to mark the question as answered

Answer (score 0):

```
` Here "this.post" not take it has instance in axios call.So you have follow like this. `
```

`var vm=this;`

`axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
                .then(response => vm.posts = response.posts)
                .catch(error => vm.posts = [{title: 'No posts found.'}])
                .finally(console.log('Posts loading complete'));`

Comment: Thank you, but your suggestion doesn't solve the issue, still no data. <posts></posts> does get updated but only to an empty <ul></ul>